# How do i use a table as input to a function in Excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that i would like to make more general. But i can't get the last part of the function to work as input to the function.

how do i use tables as input to a funktion? I would like to break out the table name and use it as input so i can use the function in other contexts.

```
Function GetTotalHours("Tablename?" As ??, columnNumber As Integer) As Integer

    For Each Row In [Tablename].Rows

        getTotalHours = getTotalHours + DateTime.Hour(Row.Columns(columnNumber).Value)

    Next

End Function
```

can i make this with a string some how?

Comment: This is a great link, have a look: http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/Excel2007TablesVBA.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tables exist as named ranges, you can access these directly with `.Range(name)`.

```
Function GetTotalHours(tableName As String, columnNumber As Integer) As Integer
    Dim r As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range(tableName).Columns(columnNumber)
    For Each c In r.Cells
        GetTotalHours = GetTotalHours + DateTime.Hour(c.Value)
    Next
End Function
```

And you could also pass the heading instead of the number:

```
Function GetTotalHoursByHeading(tableName As String, columnName As String) As Integer
    Dim r As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range(tableName & "[" & columnName & "]")
    For Each c In r.Cells
        GetTotalHoursByHeading = GetTotalHoursByHeading + DateTime.Hour(c.Value)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I still can't get this to work. Are you referring to a table as a sheet? because i mean i specific table on a sheet. not the entire sheet. like if i have a tale named trainingData on Sheet1.

Comment: Yes sorry, I really thought you mean tables = worksheets. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid a UDF, you could use this worksheet formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(HOUR(Table1[Hours]))
```